# Pivoting Custom Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So I have the following schema:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f69de

The issue that I am is that I am not sure how to pivot the custom field tables. The Custom Fields are dynamic, and have n number of fields.

How do I display the data like this:

```
Header: [PeriodEndDate], [CustomField 1], [CustomField 2], [CustomField 3]... [Customfield n]
Values (rows): 
'2013-11-24', 'Value 1', 'Value 2', 'Value 3
'2013-11-24', 'Value 1', '', 'Value 3'
```

EDIT:

I suppose the best way of showing this would be to show a real world example.

Following queries show result for **one "JOB"**, but it real query should return based on "PERIODENDDATE"

---

```
Select Id, JobId, Reg, OT, DT, Expenses, PerDiem 
From WeeklyContractBillings
WHere JobId = 44 and PeriodEndDate = '2014-05-25'


Select t.CustomFieldId, cfli.Name, cf.Name as CustomFieldName 
From Trackings t
Inner Join CustomFields cf on t.CustomFieldId = cf.CustomFieldId and cf.CustomFieldTypeId = 2 and cf.IsActive = 1 and cf.CompanyId = 25
LEFT Outer Join [ContractJobCustomFields] cjcf on t.CustomFieldId = cjcf.CustomFieldId and cjcf.JobId = 44
LEFT OUTER Join CustomFieldListItems cfli on cjcf.CustomFieldId = cfli.CustomFieldId and cjcf.CustomFieldValue = cfli.CustomFieldListItemId
Where t.ServiceOfferingId = 1
union
Select t.CustomFieldId, up.FirstName + ' ' + up.LastName as Name, cf.Name as CustomFieldName 
From Trackings t
Inner Join CustomFields cf on t.CustomFieldId = cf.CustomFieldId and cf.CustomFieldTypeId = 1 and cf.IsActive = 1 and cf.CompanyId = 25
LEFT Outer Join [ContractJobCustomFields] cjcf on t.CustomFieldId = cjcf.CustomFieldId and cjcf.JobId = 44
LEFT OUTER Join [dbo].[UserProfiles] up on cjcf.CustomFieldValue = up.UserId
Where t.ServiceOfferingId = 1
```

Here is the result of each queries respectively:

### Query 1:

```
Id  JobId   Reg OT  DT  Expenses    PerDiem
2509    44  16  0   0   0.00    0.00
```

Query 2:

---

```
CustomFieldId   Name    CustomFieldName
9   Jason Mogera    Sales Rep
10  NULL    Staffing Manager
14  NULL    Recruiter
16  Clerical    Market Segment
20  NULL    Location
```

What I am looking to do is combine these values in one row but the second query needs to be a columns based like so

```
Id  JobId   Reg OT  DT  Expenses    PerDiem Sales Rep Staffing Manager Recruiter Market Segment Location
2509 44 16  0   0   0.00    0.00   Jason Mogera None None Clerical None
```

This question was placed as duplicate but looking at it doesn't really add the complexity of having another query in there.

**NOTE EXAMPLE GIVEN IS FILTER BY JOBID, but in the actual query it needs to filter by PERIODENDDATE only. In Other words, the query will return multiple rows of Jobs and their Custom Fields respectively.**

Please help!

Comment: I'm presuming there's another key involved? I ask because the PeriodEndDate values in your example are identical.

Comment: There is Period End Dates table, but for the Weekly Table it is a date formated field as shown.

Comment: This is problematic. TSQL uses the selected columns to group by over the aggregate, so the value rows aboove will collapse. Can you add a key column to the table without headache?

Comment: I've got the template, now I need to know how you need the data - the procedure can redefine a known view, it can redefine a table-valued-function, it can be a procedure to return the data by a side-affecting select statement.

Comment: I've updated the solution. Please upvote and check if this suits your needs.

Comment: @JaazCole please look at my edit and if you can help?

Comment: My solution still works. The config portion where you create your view just needs to be altered to implement your filters.

Comment: So I tried your solution and it actually works. The question I had was for the JobWeeklysCustomFields_Pivot View. How would I account for new custom fields that get added? Will this view account for that?

Comment: The view won't, but the procedure CreatePivotViews will refresh it. There is a job creation script commented out in the code, having a job run the procedure on a schedule will adapt the view to a dynamic column set.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite involved...

First, I use a metadata tracking system, so that the single procedure can maintain many views with a single execution. The procedure alters (or creates if the pivot view does not exist). The comments below explain it relatively well. I included your sample data in here, and can answer further questions about configuration if your needs expand.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('JobWeeklysCustomFields') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW JobWeeklysCustomFields
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('Weeklys') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Weeklys
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('CustomFields') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE CustomFields
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('Jobs') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE Jobs
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('JobsCustomFields') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE JobsCustomFields
GO
/**
    JCPivot by Jaaz Cole
    Covered by Creative Commons : CC BY-SA
**/
IF OBJECT_ID('JCPivot.CreatePivotViews') IS NOT NULL DROP PROCEDURE JCPivot.CreatePivotViews
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('JCPivot.UniqueTablesAggregateOrColumn') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW JCPivot.UniqueTablesAggregateOrColumn
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('JCPivot.UniqueTablesRow') IS NOT NULL DROP VIEW JCPivot.UniqueTablesRow
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('JCPivot.TablesTo') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE JCPivot.TablesTo
GO
IF SCHEMA_ID('JCPivot') IS NOT NULL DROP SCHEMA JCPivot
GO
CREATE SCHEMA JCPivot
GO
/*
   Metadata table: distinct table and/or view names will be run
   and have a special view generated for each with a _Pivot
   suffix. So pivoting [dbo].[Emps] through this interface would
   create [dbo].[Emps_Pivot] as defined here. RowColAgg can only
   be set to 'Row', 'Col', or 'Agg'.

   'Row' column names will be selected to the left of the dataset,
       as normal columns. Limit 1 distinct column name per object.
   'Col' Will use the distinct values in this column as column headers.
       Limit 1 per object. Must have a 'Col' and an 'Agg' column 
       for an object to generate a pivot view.
   'Agg' is the column to aggregate across the 'Col' headers, and
       Also requires [AggFunction] contain only the name (no parens!)
       of an aggregate function to perform for the pivot.
       Limit 1 per object. Must have a 'Col' and an 'Agg' column 
       for an object to generate a pivot view.
*/
CREATE TABLE JCPivot.TablesTo (
      schemaName SYSNAME
    , objectName SYSNAME
    , columnName SYSNAME
    , RowColAgg VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
    , AggFunction NVARCHAR(128)
    )
GO
/* Enforce no more than 1 each Aggregate and Column Header */
CREATE VIEW JCPivot.UniqueTablesAggregateOrColumn
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT schemaName, objectName, RowColAgg FROM JCPivot.TablesTo WHERE RowColAgg = 'Agg' OR RowColAgg = 'Col';
GO    
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_UniqueAggOrCol ON JCPivot.UniqueTablesAggregateOrColumn(schemaName, objectName, RowColAgg);
GO
/* Enforce each Row header selected only once. */
CREATE VIEW JCPivot.UniqueTablesRow
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT schemaName, objectName, columnName, RowColAgg FROM JCPivot.TablesTo WHERE RowColAgg = 'Row';
GO    
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX PK_UniqueTablesRow ON JCPivot.UniqueTablesRow(schemaName, objectName, columnName);
GO
/* This Procedure Creates the Views */
CREATE PROCEDURE JCPivot.CreatePivotViews
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE
      @SchemaName SYSNAME
    , @ObjectName SYSNAME
    , @ColumnHeaderColumnName SYSNAME
    , @AggregateFunction SYSNAME
    , @AggregateColumnName SYSNAME

DECLARE
      @RowHeaderColumnNames TABLE (RowHeader SYSNAME, typeName nvarchar(128))

DECLARE ObjectCursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT schemaName, objectName
    FROM JCPivot.TablesTo
    GROUP BY schemaName, objectName
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN RowColAgg IN ('Agg','Col') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 2
    ORDER BY schemaName, objectName

OPEN ObjectCursor
FETCH NEXT FROM ObjectCursor INTO @SchemaName, @ObjectName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM @RowHeaderColumnNames
    INSERT INTO @RowHeaderColumnNames (RowHeader) SELECT columnName FROM JCPivot.TablesTo WHERE schemaName = @SchemaName AND objectName = @ObjectName AND RowColAgg = 'Row'

    SELECT @ColumnHeaderColumnName = columnName FROM JCPivot.TablesTo WHERE schemaName = @SchemaName AND objectName = @ObjectName AND RowColAgg = 'Col'
    SELECT @AggregateFunction = AggFunction, @AggregateColumnName = columnName FROM JCPivot.TablesTo WHERE schemaName = @SchemaName AND objectName = @ObjectName AND RowColAgg = 'Agg'

    --Internal declarations
    DECLARE @CursSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    DECLARE @ColumnHeaderType NVARCHAR(30)
    SELECT @ColumnHeaderType = C.DATA_TYPE
            + CASE
                WHEN C.DATA_TYPE in ('varchar','nvarchar') THEN N'(' + cast(C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH as nvarchar) + N')'
                WHEN C.DATA_TYPE = 'numeric' THEN N'(' + cast(C.NUMERIC_PRECISION as nvarchar) + N',' + cast(C.NUMERIC_SCALE as nvarchar) + N')'
                ELSE ''
            END
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
    WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME = @ColumnHeaderColumnName
        AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
        AND C.TABLE_NAME = @ObjectName

    DECLARE @RowHeaderType as nvarchar(30)
    UPDATE RHCN
    SET TypeName = C.DATA_TYPE
        + CASE
            WHEN C.DATA_TYPE in ('varchar','nvarchar') THEN N'(' + cast(C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N')'
            WHEN C.DATA_TYPE = 'numeric' THEN N'(' + cast(C.NUMERIC_PRECISION AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N',' + cast(C.NUMERIC_SCALE AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N')'
            ELSE ''
        END
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
        INNER JOIN @RowHeaderColumnNames RHCN on C.COLUMN_NAME = RHCN.RowHeader
            AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
            AND C.TABLE_NAME = @ObjectName

    DECLARE @AggregateColumnType SYSNAME = N''
    SELECT @AggregateColumnType = C.DATA_TYPE
            + CASE
                WHEN C.DATA_TYPE in ('varchar','nvarchar') THEN N'(' + cast(C.CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N')'
                WHEN C.DATA_TYPE = 'numeric' THEN N'(' + cast(C.NUMERIC_PRECISION AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N',' + cast(C.NUMERIC_SCALE AS NVARCHAR(10)) + N')'
                ELSE ''
            END
    FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS C
    WHERE C.COLUMN_NAME = @AggregateColumnName
        AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
        AND C.TABLE_NAME = @ObjectName

    DECLARE @RowHeaderNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'', @RowHeaderDeclarations NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''

    SELECT
          @RowHeaderNames = @RowHeaderNames + R.RowHeader + ', '
        , @RowHeaderDeclarations = @RowHeaderDeclarations + R.RowHeader + ' ' + R.typeName + ', '
    FROM @RowHeaderColumnNames R

    SELECT
          @RowHeaderNames = LEFT(@RowHeaderNames, LEN(@RowHeaderNames)-1)
        , @RowHeaderDeclarations = LEFT(@RowHeaderDeclarations, LEN(@RowHeaderDeclarations)-1)

    SET @CursSQL=N'
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @value ' + @ColumnHeaderType + N'
        , @ColumnHeaderNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = '''', @ColumnHeaderDeclarations NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''''

    SELECT
          @ColumnHeaderNames = @ColumnHeaderNames + QUOTENAME(' + @ColumnHeaderColumnName + N') + '',''
        , @ColumnHeaderDeclarations = @ColumnHeaderDeclarations + QUOTENAME(' + @ColumnHeaderColumnName + N') + '' ' + @AggregateColumnType + N''' + '',''
    FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@ObjectName) + N'
    WHERE ' + @ColumnHeaderColumnName + N' IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY ' + @ColumnHeaderColumnName + N'

    SELECT
          @ColumnHeaderNames = LEFT(@ColumnHeaderNames, LEN(@ColumnHeaderNames)-1)
        , @ColumnHeaderDeclarations = LEFT(@ColumnHeaderDeclarations, LEN(@ColumnHeaderDeclarations)-1)

    SET @sql=N''
    '' + CASE WHEN OBJECT_ID(''' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@ObjectName + '_Pivot') + N''') IS NOT NULL THEN ''ALTER'' ELSE ''CREATE'' END + '' VIEW ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@ObjectName + '_Pivot') + N' AS
        SELECT ' + @RowHeaderNames + N', '' + @ColumnHeaderNames + N''
        FROM (
            SELECT ' + @RowHeaderNames + N',' + QUOTENAME(@AggregateColumnName) + N' AggCol,' + QUOTENAME(@ColumnHeaderColumnName) + N' HeaderCol
            FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@ObjectName) + N'
            ) dsr
        PIVOT (
            ' + @AggregateFunction + N'(AggCol)
            FOR HeaderCol IN ('' +  @ColumnHeaderNames + '')) P''

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL'

    EXEC sp_executesql @CursSQL
    FETCH NEXT FROM ObjectCursor INTO @SchemaName, @ObjectName
END
CLOSE ObjectCursor
DEALLOCATE ObjectCursor
SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO

/* This is Job Information for Automatic Daily upkeep of the view definitions */
/*
USE [msdb]
GO
DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'UpdatePivotViews', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=2, 
        @notify_level_netsend=2, 
        @notify_level_page=2, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'PivotViews Updated', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
select @jobId
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_name=N'UpdatePivotViews', @server_name = N'<MyServer>'
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_name=N'UpdatePivotViews', @step_name=N'ExecuteScript', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'EXEC JCPivot.CreatePivotViews
', 
        @database_name=N'BRNOperational', 
        @flags=0
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name=N'UpdatePivotViews', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @start_step_id=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=2, 
        @notify_level_netsend=2, 
        @notify_level_page=2, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'PivotViews Updated', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', 
        @notify_email_operator_name=N'', 
        @notify_netsend_operator_name=N'', 
        @notify_page_operator_name=N''
GO
USE [msdb]
GO
DECLARE @schedule_id int
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_name=N'UpdatePivotViews', @name=N'Daily', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=4, 
        @freq_interval=1, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
        @active_start_date=20140613, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=0, 
        @active_end_time=235959, @schedule_id = @schedule_id OUTPUT
select @schedule_id
GO
*/

/** BEGIN CONFIG **/
/* Your schema... */
CREATE TABLE Jobs
    ([JobId] int, [Name] nvarchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO Jobs
    ([JobId], [Name])
VALUES
    (1,'Job A'),
    (2,'Job B'),
    (3,'Job C')
;


GO
CREATE TABLE Weeklys
    ([Id] int, [JobId] int, [PeriodEndDate] nvarchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO Weeklys
    ([Id], [JobId], [PeriodEndDate])
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2013-11-24'),
    (2, 1, '2013-11-24'),
    (3, 2, '2013-11-24'),
    (4, 2, '2013-12-22'),
    (5, 3, '2013-12-22')
;
GO
CREATE TABLE CustomFields
    ([CustomFieldId] int, [CompanyId] int, [Name] nvarchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO CustomFields
    ([CustomFieldId], [CompanyId], [Name])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Custom Field 1'),
    (2, 1, 'Custom Field 2'),
    (3, 2, 'Custom Field 3'),
    (4, 2, 'Custom Field 4'),
    (5, 3, 'Custom Field 5')
;
GO
CREATE TABLE JobsCustomFields
    ([JobId] int, [CustomFieldId] int, [CustomFieldValue] nvarchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO JobsCustomFields
    ([JobId], [CustomFieldId], [CustomFieldValue])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'Value 1'),
    (1, 2, 'Value 1'),
    (1, 3, 'Value 1')
;
GO
/* A new view... */
CREATE VIEW JobWeeklysCustomFields AS
    SELECT w.Id, w.PeriodEndDate, CF.CompanyId, J.JobId, J.Name AS JobName, CF.Name AS CustomFieldName, JCF.CustomFieldValue
    FROM Weeklys W
        LEFT JOIN Jobs J on J.JobId = W.JobId
        LEFT JOIN JobsCustomFields JCF ON JCF.JobId = J.JobId
        LEFT JOIN CustomFields CF ON JCF.CustomFieldId = CF.CustomFieldId
GO
/* Define the Pivot Metadata... */
INSERT INTO JCPivot.TablesTo (schemaName, objectName, columnName , RowColAgg , AggFunction)
    VALUES ('dbo', 'JobWeeklysCustomFields', 'CustomFieldName', 'Col', NULL);
INSERT INTO JCPivot.TablesTo (schemaName, objectName, columnName , RowColAgg , AggFunction)
    VALUES ('dbo', 'JobWeeklysCustomFields', 'CustomFieldValue', 'Agg', 'max');
INSERT INTO JCPivot.TablesTo (schemaName, objectName, columnName , RowColAgg , AggFunction)
    VALUES ('dbo', 'JobWeeklysCustomFields', 'Id', 'Row', NULL);
INSERT INTO JCPivot.TablesTo (schemaName, objectName, columnName , RowColAgg , AggFunction)
    VALUES ('dbo', 'JobWeeklysCustomFields', 'PeriodEndDate', 'Row', NULL);
INSERT INTO JCPivot.TablesTo (schemaName, objectName, columnName , RowColAgg , AggFunction)
    VALUES ('dbo', 'JobWeeklysCustomFields', 'CompanyId', 'Row', NULL);
INSERT INTO JCPivot.TablesTo (schemaName, objectName, columnName , RowColAgg , AggFunction)
    VALUES ('dbo', 'JobWeeklysCustomFields', 'JobId', 'Row', NULL);
INSERT INTO JCPivot.TablesTo (schemaName, objectName, columnName , RowColAgg , AggFunction)
    VALUES ('dbo', 'JobWeeklysCustomFields', 'JobName', 'Row', NULL);

/** END CONFIG **/
/* Run the Procedure to generate/refresh the pivot view */
EXEC JCPivot.CreatePivotViews

/* Enjoy the fruits. */
SELECT * FROM JobWeeklysCustomFields_Pivot
```

Comment: The thing that I am unsure of is this PIVOT (
  MAX(Attrib_Value) FOR FieldName IN
  ([CustomField 1], [CustomField 2], [CustomField 3])
 ) p. Since I dont' know how many custom fields will it have. That part is dynamic.

Comment: Then you'll need a dynamic SQL solution, which are possible, but quite a bit more work and knowledge involved. A specialized one for this table may not be that bad, though. I'll see if I can't come up with something.

Comment: @JazzCole any luck sir?

Comment: Actually, yes and no. I created the procedure before the holiday weekend, then forgot. I have something that will select data, but it doesn't return the data in a standard way. Instead it's a procedure that runs a select statement. My next question was - are you needing it returned in terms of a view, a TVF, or is the select statement running going to be enough? It could be set up as a procedure that redefines a view when run.

Comment: @jmogera, are you still in need of a procedure for returning flexible fields?

Comment: Yeah I am. I still havn't figured it out yet.

Comment: This solution may be a bit heavy handed...

Comment: Down voted because it works, even if "a bit heavy handed"? Offer an alternative, or constructive feedback, please.

Comment: I do like the solution, much faster then doing with EntityFramework. I will keep the question if there are faster solution.